# Convert DateTime to ticks in .NET?

Tags: .net, datetime

How to convert one `DateTime` to ticks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) property:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
long ticks = now.Ticks;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static long ConvertDateTimeToTicks(DateTime datetime)
    {
       long  ticks=datetime.Ticks;
       return ticks;
    } 

  static DateTime ConvertTicksToDateTime(long ticks)
    {
       DateTime datetime= new DateTime(ticks);
       return datetime;
    }
```